# Insert selected filename while copying in Midnight Commander

Tags: rename, file-copy, mc

Is it possible to paste the selected filename into the copy popup, so when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> this filename will be in the 'to' section, so I can adjust it?

For example:

I want to copy `/home/piotr/testFile.log` to `/home/piotr/testFile2.log`.
I open both panels in the same directory and hit F5, but the 'to' value is: `/home/piotr` and I would like it to be `/home/piotr/testFile.log`, so I can simply adjust the name instead of typing it from the scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> instead (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> for renaming) – the dialog will have the *to* field filled with current file's name (without the path).

Sadly those combinations not work in certain circumstances. No idea if it depends on MC build, terminal or some used library. So I also added this in ~/.mc/menu as an alternative:

```
5       Copy
        read -e -i "%f" -p 'Copy file : ' name
        [[ "$name" && "$name" != "%f" ]] && cp "%f" "$name"

6       Rename
        read -e -i "%f" -p 'Rename file : ' name
        [[ "$name" && "$name" != "%f" ]] && mv "%f" "$name"
```

Then I just select the file, hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> (or <kbd>6</kbd> for renaming) then edit the name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It requires `bash` 4 or newer, due to the `read`'s `-i` option.

Comment: Works like a charm (at least in my build)! Much obliged.